# Firebase Test Lab - Not authorised to use project

Tags: android, firebase, testing, firebase-test-lab

I followed this tutorial to create tests in android studio: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests#run-ctl. I successfully ran those tests on my physical device. Then I created the test run configuration for test lab, also followed the same tutorial. When I want to run this configuration I am receiving the following error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Why am I not authorised for my own project? I was able to add my firebase project normally. I am using only free spark billing in Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you prepare your test run configuration, make sure you select your Firebase project (the one you created and to which you have access) from the list of all cloud projects you see. Also, if you created your project after your login in Android Studio, it might help to log out and re-login (using the icon in the top right corner of Android Studio).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sure that I selected the right Firebase project and I also tried to logout and login again. It didn't help, too.

Comment: I just followed the tutorial steps from scratch, creating a new Firebase project (which is by default Spark) using my non-Google account, and I did not encounter any issues with getting the default bucket name. So, I assume there might be something specific to your setup.

1) I assume you have not modified any properties of your newly created Firebase project.

2) What version of Android Studio are you using?

3) How many projects do you see in the list of projects to choose from for your test run configuration?

Comment: Thank you again. 1) didn't modify anything. 2) 3.1.4. 3) I have only one project in that account, so only one. But I am not an owner of the project, only editor. Couldn't that be a problem? Btw, I am now able to test my project directly on firebase console website. This works well. But still can't test from Android studio.

Comment: Thank you for the additional details! Being an editor rather than an owner of a Firebase project should be fine (to confirm, I used an editor user for my project and it worked as expected). For a sanity check, do you mind creating a new Firebase project (where, by default, you would be the owner and the only member)? Since you are using a Spark billing anyway, this should not be a problem. After you create a new Firebase project, log out from your account in Android Studio (AS) and close AS. Then, start AS, login to your account, and use your new project in your test configuration. Thanks!

Comment: Finally today I was able to get back to this project and also was successful in testing. I just tried to re-login again and I changed the test devices configuration and somehow it started to work. I don't really know what helped. However thank you very much for your assistance.